# beautiful soup doesn't find all <p> tags

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract the text between `<p>` tags in a new article. 
The article is broken into multiple paragraphs.

I want to loop through them and get all the text but strangely beautiful soup only returns the 3 first `<p>` tags until it reaches `<style>` tag.

Here is the structure of the webpage:
[image]

and here is my code :

```
link = 'https://www.moneycontrol.com/news/india/pe-vc-investments-in-india-may-dip-up-to-60-in-2020-due-to-covid-19-ey-5172131.html'

news_page = requests.get(link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(news_page.content, 'html.parser')
head_line = soup.find('h1', {'class': 'artTitle'})
sub_head = soup.find('h2', {'class': 'subhead'})
news_content_section = soup.find('div', {'class': 'arti-flow'})
desired_tags = news_content_section.find_all('p')
for items in desired_tags:
   print(items.get_text())
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I changed the find method from `find_all` to `findAll`. It got better results for me but not everything. Some of the paragraphs you want have another tag under the `p` tag called `'strong'`. I could not get the elements under there. Here is what I have.

```
news_content_section = soup.find('div', {'class': 'arti-flow'})
for tag in soup.findAll('p'):
    print(tag.get_text())
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! yes I tried that , the strange part is, I checked other pages with the same structure and some of them worked fine and I got all <p> tags! I have no idea what is the issue here!!

Answer (score 0):

There are different options to get your goal, simplest one is to call `get_text()` from the `<div>`

```
soup.select_one('div.arti-flow').get_text(' ', strip=True)
```

That will cover following points:

- also get text from `<strong>`
- last paragraph that is not wrapped with `<p>`

#### Output

```
Indian private equity and venture capital investments in 2020 are expected to crash by up to 60 percent, a direct upshot of the wrenching grip of novel coronavirus, or COVID-19, on the economy and businesses, said a new study. PE and VC investments — including sectors such as real estate, infrastructure and credit — are presaged to settle in the range of $19 billion to $26 billion this year, dropping by45-60 percent from the 2019 levels of $48 billion, according to the study by EY, an advisory firm. The waning appetite of PE investors and VC in deals is bad news for enterprises looking to raise money and ride out the troubles sown by the virus. Bad news for deals The gloomy outlook doesn’t end there. PE and VC exits are also expected to drop by 50-67 percent compared with last year, meaning deal making will move at a snail’s pace in 2020, according to the report. Monthly Indian PE and VC investments slipped below the $1 billion mark for the first time in the past three years in March, falling to $818 million. Exits stood at $1.1 billion largely due to one mammoth deal — the offer for sale worth $1 billion by PE investors in the mega SBI Cards IPO. Fund raising has also taken a hit in March with the total amount pegged at a mere $85 million. Close COVID-19 Vaccine Frequently Asked Questions View more How does a vaccine work? A vaccine works by mimicking a natural infection. A vaccine not only induces immune response to protect people from any future COVID-19 infection, but also helps quickly build herd immunity to put an end to the pandemic. Herd immunity occurs when a sufficient percentage of a population becomes immune to a disease, making the spread of disease from person to person unlikely. The good news is that SARS-CoV-2 virus has been fairly stable, which increases the viability of a vaccine. How many types of vaccines are there? There are broadly four types of vaccine — one, a vaccine based on the whole virus (this could be either inactivated, or an attenuated [weakened] virus vaccine); two, a non-replicating viral vector vaccine that uses a benign virus as vector that carries the antigen of SARS-CoV; three, nucleic-acid vaccines that have genetic material like DNA and RNA of antigens like spike protein given to a person, helping  human cells decode genetic material and produce the vaccine; and four, protein subunit vaccine wherein the recombinant proteins of SARS-COV-2 along with an adjuvant (booster) is given as a vaccine. What does it take to develop a vaccine of this kind? Vaccine development is a long, complex process. Unlike drugs that are given to people with a diseased, vaccines are given to healthy people and also vulnerable sections such as children, pregnant women and the elderly. So rigorous tests are compulsory. History says that the fastest time it took to develop a vaccine is five years, but it usually takes double or sometimes triple that time. View more Show Related stories COVID-19 vaccine | Bharat Biotech has been submitting data regularly, very quickly: WHO on Covaxin E... Hertz says it may expand supply of Teslas to Uber to 150,000 Karnataka Bank Q2 net profit up 5% at Rs 126 crore A senior investment banker with a global advisory firm said PE exits through the primary market route via initial public offerings will be delayed due to the current subdued environment. “Rather than reconcile to low valuations, most funds will prefer to wait it out and push for listing at a later date,” he said, asking not to be named. That said, according to this person, the current low valuations may nudge a few India-focused funds to invest in companies and take opportunistic bets. In the absence of a widely accepted vaccine for COVID-19, it is near impossible to predict the duration of the pandemic and the extent of the consequent economic damage. So what’s Plan B for PE funds and venture capital firms? Both types of investors are expected to focus on the business continuity of their portfolio companies and rely on private investments in public equity transactions in the near term.\xa0 Growth capital investments and structured credit deals are likely to be the flavour of the season, according to the EY report. “At present, private equity funds are focused on mentoring portfolio companies. I expect that in a few months, they will start deploying their dry powder as several companies will need cash and deals will be re-priced. The trajectory will vary by sector,” says Cyril Shroff, Managing Partner at law firm Cyril Amarchand Mangaldas. Yogesh Singh, a senior partner at law firm Trilegal, expects many structured, special situation and distress deals to materialise because businesses will need to continue and tide over these (difficult) times. “Assuming the lockdown is over, bridge financing and mezzanine (mixture of debt and equity) deals will pick up quite a bit in the third quarter,” he said. Bye-bye buyouts Additionally, buyout activity may be muted until the end of the third quarter/beginning of the fourth quarter of 2020 and is likely to be led later by conglomerates eager to divest non-core businesses, said the study. “Buyout deals in any case take longer to consummate. In today’s scenario, neither the buyer nor the seller is sure about the correct price as business realities have drastically changed and need to be re-assessed. The level of due diligence will also be much higher in a control transaction and will take longer. Deal discussions may continue, but announcements are likely to get delayed,” said Deepak Sharma, MD and Head (M&A) at Axis Capital. In terms of sectoral themes, the EY report has picked technology, consumer goods, pharmaceuticals as well as sub-sectors such as medical supply and services, biotech, agricultural products, chemicals, edtech and e-commerce as the first to find favour with investors. Investments in sectors like financial services, fintech, infrastructure, real estate and healthcare are expected to slow down, it said. Ultimately, experts believe a lot depends on timely and well-coordinated action from the central and state governments. “Over the next two quarters, we expect more clarity to emerge on the spread/control of the epidemic, removal of restrictions, revival of demand and supply chains and government response by way of fiscal and policy stimulus,” said Vivek Soni, Partner and National Leader for Private Equity Services, EY India.
```